# Jenkins job to list out all the PRs created till date given repository name as input to the job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, pull-request

Here comes the requirement as -

I need to create a Jenkins job either a pipeline (groovy) or in UI, which is to list out all the PRs created till date under a repository by giving the repo name as an input to the jenkins job.

Can someone provide any leads???

Answer (score 1):

Github API to list all the PR's (closed/opened/merged)

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls?state=all
```

More details: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests

Here is the pipeline script to list all the PR's of a Github repo. Also, I have passed `${repoName}` as an input String parameter to accept the repo name.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('List all PRs') {
            steps {
                sh """ curl -XGET "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/${repoName}/pulls?state=all" """ 
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note:** In the pipeline script, replace `octocat` with the name of the owner of the repo.

Comment: Hi Sourav, thanks for your response. When I tried the method which you given am getting below error.

+ curl -XGET 'https://api.github.com/repos/(owner-name)/ap-cob-composite/pulls?state=all'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.github.com; Unknown error

NOTE - owner-name is given proper in the jenkinsfile.

SO what did I do before getting this err

Comment: continued..

I just added the whole content as per your answer in a Jenkinsfile and ran the job, in the jenkins log I got this error.

Do I need to do anything at bitbucket side, could you please explain me.

Comment: Are you using bitbucket ? If yes, then the API used in the answer is not in your case as it is **Github API** Try the same pipeline script but use the bitbucket api.

Comment: Bitbucket API for retrieving pull requests can be find in this [link](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests#get)

Comment: you need to provide authentication details in curl command. Try like this `curl -u user:password -X GET https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests?state=ALL`